# Nextflow process run in gcp stays idle forever after crashing - how to increase gcsfuse max opt?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, nextflow

I am running a nextflow pipeline in GCP ("batch"). This pipeline has multiple processes and the first half complete successfully.

However, when it reaches a specific process, it doesn't even start the command but rather stays idle indefinitely.

From within the VM, I tried to `ls` inside the two storage buckets that are mounted on it in `/mnt/disks` and required by my process. Note that these two buckets are required by the other processes too and they work in those.

However, in this particular process, one of the two buckets is inaccessible and I cannot ls inside, it gets stuck forever.

I am not sure if this `ls` issue is related with the process in general being stuck, but I have no idea where to start debugging it because there is no error coming out of it.

The pipeline works well locally.

Anyone has any idea on where I could start looking for answers?

EDIT #1: **I figured why the `ls` is stuck**

According to [this post](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/issues/1603) and [this post](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/issues/513), there may be a limit to the number of concurrent operations accepted by a bucket mounted with gcsfuse.

EDIT #2: **What could be wrong with the command**

I haven't posted the command yet because it is huge and mostly functional, but I finally narrowed it down to what it could be.

The command is structured like this:

```
        ${VEP} \
        --offline --cache --force_overwrite --show_ref_allele \
        --numbers \
        --fork ${task.cpus} \
        --refseq \
        --cache_version ${params.database.vep_cache_version} \
        --dir_cache database/${params.database.cache_VEP} \
        --fasta database/${params.database.fasta_VEP_gz} \
        --dir_plugins ${VEP_PLUGINS} \
        --assembly \${ASSEMBLY} \
        --custom database/${params.database.clinvar},ClinVar,vcf,exact,0,CLNSIG,CLNREVSTAT,CLNDN,CLNDISDB,CLNALLELEID \
        --custom database/${params.database.ExAC},exac03,vcf,exact,0,AF,AC,AC_Het,AC_Hom,AC_AFR,AC_AMR,AC_EAS,AC_FIN,AC_NFE,AC_OTH,AC_SAS,AN_AFR,AN_AMR,AN_EAS,AN_FIN,AN_NFE,AN_OTH,AN_SAS,Het_AFR,Het_AMR,Het_EAS,Het_FIN,Het_NFE,Het_OTH,Het_SAS,Hom_AFR,Hom_AMR,Hom_EAS,Hom_FIN,Hom_NFE,Hom_OTH,Hom_SAS \
        --custom database/${params.database.gnomad_exomes},gnomad_exomes,vcf,exact,0,AF,AF_afr,AF_amr,AF_asj,AF_eas,AF_fin,AF_nfe,AF_oth,AF_sas,AF_XY,AF_XX,popmax \
        --custom database/${params.database.gnomad_genomes},gnomad_genomes,vcf,exact,0,AF,AF_afr,AF_amr,AF_asj,AF_eas,AF_fin,AF_nfe,AF_oth,AF_sas,AF_XY,AF_XX,popmax \
        --custom database/${params.database.ESP6500SI},esp6500siv2,vcf,exact,0,MAF \
        --af_1kg \
        --hgvs --hgvsg --symbol --nearest symbol --distance 1000 \
        --canonical --exclude_predicted \
        --regulatory \
        -i ${norm_vcf} \
        -o ${sample_id}_VEP_output.raw.vcf \
        -vcf --flag_pick_allele_gene \
        --pick_order mane,canonical,appris,tsl,biotype,ccds,rank,length
```

Where you can see that there are **5** `--custom` databases. This command with 5 --custom annotations worked.

However, in my original command I pass 9 custom databases and 9 custom plugins, which are processed concurrently by the program (VEP).

Locally, this 9+9 configuration works, but in gcp it doesn't. I am beginning to think that it may be due to *gcsfuse itself*. However I have no idea of how to debug this or control this from nextflow.

Anyone has had experiences before with a situation like this?

Comment: Please share code for the process that gets stuck including the relevant parts of the config file. 

Are you using a fusion enabled version?

Comment: No, I'm using google batch which performs a gcsfuse automatically but no fusion+wave. About the code, since it's a huge command, I'm trying to debug it parameter by parameter first.

Comment: @dthorbur I have shared some more details.